# Android dex injection with Proguard and Maven

Tags: android, maven, proguard, dex

In my app I'm using dex injection for some business logic.
I'm using maven to build the project and that dex separatly with maven plugin `com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2`

The connection from this dex to my app is through an interface.
I need to find a way to be able to obfuscate my app and that external code with the same names.

example of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>

                    <dex>
                        <jvmArguments>
                            <jvmArgument>-Xms256m</jvmArgument>
                            <jvmArgument>-Xmx1500m</jvmArgument>
                        </jvmArguments>

                    </dex>
                    <proguard>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <proguardJarPath>${env.ANDROID_HOME}/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar</proguardJarPath>
                        <jvmArguments>
                            <jvmArgument>-Xms256m</jvmArgument>
                            <jvmArgument>-Xmx1500m</jvmArgument>
                        </jvmArguments>
                    </proguard>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Is that like multi dex or I need something else?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the configuration option `-applymapping` to re-use an existing mapping. So the workflow would be to build the additional dex file using ProGuard and use the resulting mapping file when building the whole application. You should also use the following option (both for dex and application) to reduce the risk of problems.

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
```